# How can I get value in OnItemClickListener from adapter?

Tags: android, android-adapter, onitemclicklistener

Please help get the value of "KEY_ID" from OnItemClickListener

Adapter code:

```
public int getCount() {
return data.size();
}
public Object getItem(int position) {
return position;
}
public long getItemId(int position) {
return position;
}
```

Activity code:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

map.put(MainActivity.KEY_ID,MainActivity.parser.getValue(e,MainActivity.KEY_ID));
songsList.add(map);

adapter = new LazyAdapter(getActivity(), songsList);
list.setAdapter(adapter);

st.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
int position, long id) {

String sss = ???????????????????????????????????? value of KEY_ID
}
});
```

Please HELP.
Thanks for any help you can provide

Answer (score 1):

Try this changing your onItemClick to this:

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {

        String sss = songsList.get(position).get(MainActivity.KEY_ID);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the adapter, it more reliable..because it corresponds to what is being currently displayed on the UI:

```
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
       int position, long id) {
       String value = ((Map<String, String>)adapter.getItem(position)).get(MainActivity.KEY_ID);

     // 'adapter' can be either the field variable of the one you instantiated above OR by accessing the parameter 'parent' like this: parent.getAdapter()

    }
```

Comment: Indeed, this is more reliable than my initial answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Not work. Error - "Map<String,String> cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: Did you import? java.util.Map... or do the one you were already using: HashMap<String, String>

Comment: ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

Comment: import java.util.Map;   The Map is more generic, usually we refer to Map (interface) instead of HashMap which is the implementation. But in your code you can use the one you like, both will work.

Comment: what is the problem now? the import?

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer

Comment: are you sure you're using getItem(position)?? and not the getItemId(position) ?

Comment: String sss = ((Map<String, String>)adapter.getItem(position)).get(MainActivity.KEY_ID);

Comment: then the getItem() from this LazyAdapter is returning integer instead of the map. can i see the code of the lazyadapter?

Comment: Add it to the question.. or just paste the relevant part, like the getItem method.

Comment: You see? The problem is right there.. It's returning position which is integer.

Comment: You should return something like data.get(position) considering that 'data' is the list of maps.

Comment: getItemId is not the issue.

Comment: Sorry, but im nueb... How can I FIX it ?

Comment: Inside the getItem() method, you put: return data.get(position) ;

Comment: Java is a requirement for Android, skipping Java and to learn Android is not the way to go. Good luck man!

Comment: Hehehe you're welcome! Java is the short cut :-) greetings from Brazil!

Comment: greetings from Ukraine !! Thanks